# How do I get input from the DOM and then send a response back in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

Basically I'm trying to have the user be able to input something into a form, for it to be sent back to the server so I can then process it and then send back a response that updates the DOM to show the result. I've tried figuring out jQuery and cheerio but I'm just confused and not sure exactly how I can do what I want

Comment: A google search is a good place to start.  Lots of tutorials on the web for sending form input from a browser to your server.  Here's [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is too broad and could be interpreted/accomplished in many different ways. Please show concrete code and add details.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must make HTTP Request POST to finish it, i have an article that can guide you, and i hope it helps

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started:

```
let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector("form")))
fetch(url, {
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(r => r.json().then(responseData => {
  document.querySelector("p").innerText = responseData.message
}))
```

Then you have to work out the backend code and adjust what I posted here to suit your needs.